# How do I wait until QWidget::repaint is finished?

Tags: c++, qt, repaint, qpainter, qwt

I have a gui with a `QWidget` (specifically, a `QwtPlot` but I don't think the problem is `Qwt`-specific) which I redraw using a timer.  I.e., every 100ms `QWidget::update` gets called, via `QwtPlot::replot`.  When the timer interval too small, or the number of samples in the `QwtCurve` (`QPolygonF`) is too large, the program crashes, usually with an error message like this:

> QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
>
> QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.
>
> QPainter::translate: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.
>
> QPainter::save: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::setClipRect: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::save: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
>
> QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
>
> QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
>
> QPainter::save: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
>
> QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
>
> QPainter::save: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::Pen: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
>
> QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
>
> QPainter::save: Painter not active ...

The standard reason for a 'recursive repaint' error is if you call `paint()` within `update` or something like that, but I am not subclassing `QWidget` so this never happens in my code.  `Qwt` has been around long enough that I'm pretty sure that no fundamental error such as this is present in that code.  This leaves me thinking that `update` is getting called before the last draw has finished, which leads me to my question: Is there a way to find out whether a repaint is complete, and so, skip a given repaint if the last one hasn't finished at the time the timer fires again?

Edit: I use a timer because the calculations which generate the data to be drawn are done in a worker thread.  I use a `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` for this signal and guarantee with an `assert()` that replot is only ever called from the main thread.  This why I don't use the autoreplot functionality of `QwtPlot`, the program will crash if I try.

Comment: The update() function is always safe to call. It's only when repaint() is called directly that you're going to run into problems like this.

Comment: Why you call update? Changes in `QwtPlot` data should do this automatically (proper view and model behavior - your code is a controller).

Comment: @MarekR Please see my edit.  `setAutoReplot(true)` won't work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris says the update() call should not cause any problem.

It might help to install a custom message handler via qInstallMsgHandler() in your application. This way you can get a break point at the time when the warning appears and check out when/why this exactly happens.

Comment: Thanks, though this should really be a comment not an answer.  I tried this but I haven't gotten anything useful that I didn't already get from the debugger running in debug mode.